# How to install Jekyll the proper way?

Tags: ubuntu, jekyll

I installed Jekyll using `sudo gem install jekyll`, but it looks like Jekyll is not installed properly.

```
ri@ri-desktop:~/nightybuild$ jekyll
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find jekyll (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:22:in `<main>'
```

What is the proper way to install Jekyll?

Comment: I recommend not using `sudo` with `gem install`, it can cause issues with permissions. Is your gem directory added to your $PATH?

Comment: how can i check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing  `gem install`.

If you want to remove the JavaScript error, then try running `sudo apt-get install nodejs`.